# How to start with a specific index - basic jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am using a slider [Basic Jquery Slider](http://www.basic-slider.com/)

I want to start with 2nd index or sometimes 3rd index.

How can I achieve this?
I tried options below, but did not work:

```
$('#banner-slides').bjqs({
   animtype     : 'slide',
   currentslide : 2,
   currentindex : 1
});
```

Comment: That plugin has no option to start at a specific slide. It does have `randomstart:true`. With that it will start at a random slide.

Comment: This should have been an option.

Comment: Yup, you may want to talk to the developer or try and add the option to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    this.goto = function(position){ // this keyword is added here
        state.animating = false;
        if(settings.animtype === "slide")
            position = position + 1;
        go(false,position);
    }
    init();
    return this; // newly added code
```

You can add the above script to the bjqs-1.3.js file and initialize the slider like

```
var bannerslides = $('#banner-slides').bjqs({
   animtype     : 'slide'
});
```

then use `bannerslides.goto(1)` to go to first slide

you can create multiple sliders like

```
var bannerslides1 = $('#banner-slides1').bjqs({
   animtype     : 'slide'
});


var bannerslides2 = $('#banner-slides2').bjqs({
   animtype     : 'slide'
});
```

and use it like `bannerslides1.goto(1)` to go to first slide of `bannerslides1` slider and `bannerslides2.goto(1)` to go to first slide of `bannerslides2` slider

I hope you can calculate the slidenumbers

NOTE : I haven't tested fully.

**UPDATE**

I have added one more condition to make it work if the animation was `fade`

**UPDATE**

Find the new code and let me know if it works

Comment: Perfect. used $('#banner-slides').bjqs.goto(2);   Thanks

Comment: Its not working with multiple sliders :( $('#banner-slides-1').bjqs.goto(2); $('#banner-slides-2').bjqs.goto(2); either slide 1 or 2

Comment: Great. It worked. just updated answer, removed currentslide : 2, currentindex : 1... was not working