# basic jquery slider - how to call specific slide

Tags: jquery, slider

Does anyone know how to call a specific slide of basic jquery slider from an element anywhere on the page?
That's the slider http://www.basic-slider.com  I couldn't find anything helpful in the documentation nor google

I don't wanna use the built-in pagination but rather have my own thumbnails underneath the slider and call a specific slide by clicking on them.

Comment: You want to replace the built in pagination with your own thumbnails, then have a specific slide display when one of the thumbnails is clicked on?

Comment: Well let's just assume I have an img tag somewhere on the page and want to call slide nr. 15 when clicking on it for instance (to make it an easier example)

Comment: Might be possible, not sure. If you post a JSfiddle or code example in your question, I don't mind taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [this](https://github.com/jcobb/basic-jquery-slider/pull/195) pull request created by me long ago

also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403703/how-to-start-with-a-specific-index-basic-jquery-slider/26404699#26404699) stackoverflow answer which is again answered by me.